# How can I reuse HTML attribute values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In the following code, I have the `min = 0, max = 99` values duplicated in the `Html.EditorFor()` methods.
What's the best way to make this more DRY?

```
<div id="Team1PlayerScores">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Team1.Players.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].GoalsForCurrentGame, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 0, max = 99, onchange = "updateTeamScore('Team1PlayerScores', 'Team1_GoalsForCurrentGame')" } })
    }
</div>

<div id="Team2PlayerScores">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Team2.Players.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Team2.Players[i].Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Team2.Players[i].GoalsForCurrentGame, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 0, max = 99, onchange = "updateTeamScore('Team2PlayerScores', 'Team2_GoalsForCurrentGame')" } })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: How about creating a `Dictionary<string,object>` and add required attributes from it (because `htmlAttributes` has type of `IDictionary<string,object>`)? But still have no idea how to detect different `Team` instance to adjust `onchange` attribute.

Comment: If you stop polluting your markup with behavior and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) then you can define the attributes once - `var attributes = new { ... };` and `@Html.EditorFor(m => ..., new { htmlAttributes = attributes })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to remove the duplication of the "magic numbers" in your code, rather than in the generated HTML, you could replace the numbers with values from your Model:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public Team Team2 { get; set; }

    public int MinimumGoals => 0;
    public int MaximumGoals => 99;
}
```

And an update to the View to utilise it:

```
<div id="Team1PlayerScores">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Team1.Players.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Team1.Players[i].GoalsForCurrentGame, 
         new { htmlAttributes = new { min = Model.MinimumGoals, max = Model.MaximumGoals, 
         onchange = "updateTeamScore('Team1PlayerScores', 'Team1_GoalsForCurrentGame')" } })
    }
</div>

<div id="Team2PlayerScores">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Team2.Players.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Team2.Players[i].Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Team2.Players[i].GoalsForCurrentGame, 
         new { htmlAttributes = new { min = Model.MinimumGoals, max = Model.MaximumGoals,
         onchange = "updateTeamScore('Team2PlayerScores', 'Team2_GoalsForCurrentGame')" } })
    }
</div>
```

I've dropped the values in as read-only properties, but how you implement them into the Model is up-to you.